# Why I'm getting trash on this pipe?

Tags: c, unix, named-pipes

I'm running a full-duplex server/client code I found on Oracle's website:

When writing ./fd_client hahaha I get something like:

HAHAHA0�`$0`

The upper case is OK (it's what the server it's supposed to return) but, how the hell do I avoid that trailing trash?

fd_client.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "fullduplex.h" /* For name of the named-pipe */


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int wrfd, rdfd, numread;
    char rdbuf[MAX_BUF_SIZE];

    /* Check if an argument was specified. */

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage : %s \n", argv[0]);
        exit (0);
    }

    /* Open the first named pipe for writing */
    wrfd = open(NP1, O_WRONLY);

    /* Open the second named pipe for reading */
    rdfd = open(NP2, O_RDONLY);

    /* Write to the pipe */
    write(wrfd, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));

    /* Read from the pipe */
    numread = read(rdfd, rdbuf, MAX_BUF_SIZE);

    rdbuf[numread] = '0';

    printf("Full Duplex Client : Read From the  Pipe : %s\n", rdbuf);

    return 0;
}
```

fd_server.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "fullduplex.h" /* For name of the named-pipe */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rdfd, wrfd, ret_val, count, numread;
    char buf[MAX_BUF_SIZE];

    /* Create the first named - pipe */
    ret_val = mkfifo(NP1, 0666);

    if ((ret_val == -1) && (errno != EEXIST)) {
        perror("Error creating the named pipe");
        exit (0);
    }

    ret_val = mkfifo(NP2, 0666);

    if ((ret_val == -1) && (errno != EEXIST)) {
        perror("Error creating the named pipe");
        exit (0);
    }

    /* Open the first named pipe for reading */
    rdfd = open(NP1, O_RDONLY);

    /* Open the second named pipe for writing */
    wrfd = open(NP2, O_WRONLY);

    /* Read from the first pipe */
    numread = read(rdfd, buf, MAX_BUF_SIZE);

    buf[numread] = '0';

    printf("Full Duplex Server : Read From the pipe : %s \n", buf);

    /* Convert to the string to upper case */
    count = 0;
    while (count < numread) {
        buf[count] = toupper(buf[count]);
        count++;
    }

    /* 
     * Write the converted string back to the second 
     * pipe 
     */    
    write(wrfd, buf, strlen(buf));
}
```

fullduplex.h

```
#define NP1     "/tmp/np1"
#define NP2     "/tmp/np2"
#define MAX_BUF_SIZE    255
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean:

```
rdbuf[numread] = '\0';
```

buf in fd_server.c has the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, I did both changes, the garbage is gone, but now I'm gettig a trailing 0 in the response.

Comment: Like: HAHAHA0 in the response

Comment: @omgzor Sorry, without seeing the code I can only guess. And when you say "response" do you mean in fd_client.c or fd_server.c?

Comment: in fd_client.c, It's the same code as above with only the two changes you mention.

Comment: @omgzor are you sure you fixed both files and rebuilt both the client and the server? When I make those changes to the code above and test it, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
buf[numread] = '0';
```

is wrong. You want:

```
buf[numread] = '\0';
```

(Same with `rdbuf[numread] = '0';`.)

Comment: Thanks, I did both changes, the garbage is gone, but now I'm getting a trailing 0 in the response

Comment: Update the code in the question to your current code and maybe someone can take a stab at it. If you just leave your old code, we can't really debug your new code just by guessing.

Answer (score -1):

These lines produce bad output:

```
buf[numread] = '0';
printf("Full Duplex Server : Read From the pipe : %s \n", buf);
```

First, `buf[numread] = '0';` Overwrites your null-terminator.
With this overwritten, `printf(%s)` doesn't know where to stop printing.

The null-terminator tells C where the string ends.
After you overwrote it, C no longer knows where the end of the string is, and prints your string "HAHAHA", but keeps printing garbage after that.

Comment: Well, `read(2)` and `write(2)` don't actually care about strings and null terminators, so it isn't overriding any NUL-terminator, it's just terminating it wrong. Also, generally we refer to NULL as the 0 pointer, vs NUL as the '\0' terminator-character.